# Delete existing categories and channels and make new ones(discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need some help with a code in discord.js where I delete the existing categories and channels and then make new ones. My code edits the icon and guild name so now I'm moving onto channels and whatnot. No, this is not a nuker, I'm trying to make a server rebuilder or remodeler and things similar to that. Anyways, here is my code and by the bottom is where I'd like to implement the channel deleting and replacing.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const guild = new Discord.Guild();
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(token);

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content == "server") {
        try {
            await message.guild.setIcon("./icon.png");
            await message.guild.setName("server");
            message.channel.send("Successfully made server.");
        } catch {
            message.channel.send("Unknown error occurred while making server.");
        }
    }
});
```

If anyone could help with this, please let me know.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, It is nice that you want to implement a new feature to your bot. But how did you try to add the feature yourself? What did you researched? The server name and icon are completely irrelevant things and have nothing to do with deleting channels and categories and creating new ones. Please edit and improve your question. You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is just my current code as an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is too broad, you should try to narrow it to something specific that you are having issues with, like @Skulaurun Mrusal told you to. However, I can give you some tips on where to start:

You can access a `<Guild>`'s `<GuildChannelManager>` - a class that gives you some ways of managing the guild channels, such as deleting or creating them - through `<Guild>.channels`.

If you'd like to delete a channel from this `<Guild>` you would do `<Guild>.cache.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'channel-name').delete()`

While if you wanted to create one, you would do: `<Guild>.channels.create(...)`.

Don't forget you need the `MANAGE_CHANNELS` permission to do such operations. I hope this can help you out.